# User Control and Custom Control

Tags: user-controls, custom-controls

I'm purely new to this topics.(User Control and Custom Control)
Even i saw some other sites for learning,i'm totally confused about these topics.
Which site is best to start these topics with examples from beginning?

Answer (score 0):

I think, MSDN is the best one.

See following link :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893667